# assign template to Joomla articles and FlexiContent items without menu

Tags: joomla3.0, assign

I want to assign a template style to a category articles in joomla3. FLEXIcontent  items Indeed. 
I have a cooking category and I want it's items to have different Template Style. 
* I have many items in this category and I can't make menu for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you group articles into a category and you made a menu item for that (like blog category layout - and select the grupped articles category) then you can assign different template.

You dont have to show this menu item on frontpage. And every article what you grupped into that category will use the template selected in the menu item.

Comment: thank you. I tested what you said but since I have many template assignment in my website, a simple mistake made me think I should do something more. but because of your comment I checked it again. thank you again.